# Scroll wheel in Character Map

Tags: windows, mouse, scrolling, characters, scroll-wheel

Why can't we use the scroll wheel in the Windows Character Map?
In every version of Windows I couldn't ever scroll with the scroll wheel of the mouse, but it's the only program that behaves that way, plus the menus on some games...

Answer (score 0):

Scroll-wheel implementation is application-specific. It's up to the application's author to intentionally support the scroll-wheel.

Windows' Character Map utility hasn't been updated significantly in so long that it probably (still) predates the scroll-wheel's general existence/acceptance.

*Why* a program hasn't had that functionality added can only be answered by the author.

Comment: Thank you agent, great answer. I saw that all the windows "peripheral programs" was scroll-whell-able, but not this one in particular, that's why the question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why can't we use the scroll wheel in the Windows Character Map?

If you install [katmouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/) then you can scroll with the wheel as long as the mouse pointer is over the **scrollbar**.

> The prime purpose of the KatMouse utility is to enhance the functionality of mice with a scroll wheel, offering "universal" scrolling: moving the mouse wheel will scroll the window directly beneath the mouse cursor (not the one with the keyboard focus, which is default on Windows). This is a major increase in the usefullness of the mouse wheel.

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [katmouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: Thank you very much David. I'll try this the next time I have to edit several Excel tables and CAD drawings in parallel, through 2 monitors. This will be a great productivity enhancement.